# Function settings_fields() not recognized (Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function settings_fields())

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Im developing my first plugin, and the wordpress shows the following error when I try to access to the wp-admin:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function settings_fields() in .../plugins/wtdomcheck/admin/html/settings.php:25

### plugin file wtdomcheck.php

```
..
..
define( 'WTDOMCHECK_PLUGIN_DIR',    plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
..
..
if ( is_admin() ) {
  require_once( 'admin/wtdomcheck_admin.php' );
} else {
  require_once( 'public/wtdomcheck_front.php' );
}
..
..
```

### plugin file wtdomcheck_admin.php

```
..
..
require_once WTDOMCHECK_PLUGIN_DIR.'admin/class/class-admin.php';

if ( class_exists(admin) ) {

    $wtdomadmin = new admin();
    $wtdomadmin->register();

}
..
..
```

### plugin file class-admin.php

```
..
..
require_once 'api.php';


class admin 
{
    public $pluginName;

    public $settings;

    public $pages = array();

    public $subpages = array();


    function __construct() 
    {
        $this->pluginName = plugin_basename( __FILE__ );

        $this->settings = new ApiWpadmin();

        $this->pages = [
            [
                'page_title' => 'WT Domain Check', 
                'menu_title' => 'WTDomCheck', 
                'capability' => 'manage_options', 
                'menu_slug'  => 'wtdomaincheck', 
                'callback'   => $this->LoadSettingTemplate(), 
                'icon_url'   => 'dashicons-store', 
                'position'   => 117
            ]
        ];

        $this->subpages = [
            /*[
                'parent_slug'=> 'wtdomaincheck',
                'page_title' => 'Settings', 
                'menu_title' => 'Settings', 
                'capability' => 'manage_options', 
                'menu_slug'  => 'settings',
                'callback'   => function() { echo '<h1>Taxonomies Manager</h1>'; },
            ]*/
        ];

        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'LoadMetabox') ); 

        add_action('edit_form_after_title', array( $this, 'DelAllMetaboxes') );

    }



    //
    // PARAM
    // Register all the actions and filters for the Admin area
    //
    public function register() 
    {
        //Call the concatenated API method to contruct the menu, and submenu
        $this->settings->AddPages( $this->pages )->WithSubPage( 'Settings' )->AddSubPages( $this->subpages )->register();

        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'SaveSettings') );

        add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_'.WTDOMCHECK_PLUGIN_NAME, array($this->settings, 'AddCustomLinks') );

        add_action("manage_posts_custom_column",  array( $this, 'EditColumns') );

        add_filter("manage_edit-wt_whoisservers_columns", array( $this, 'FilterColumns') );
    }


    //
    // PARAM
    // Loads the template that shows the settings page
    //
    public function LoadSettingTemplate()
    {
        include_once WTDOMCHECK_PLUGIN_DIR.'admin/html/settings.php';
    }
```

### plugin file settings.php

```
<?php

//require_once '/www/lr-webstower.com.ar/htdocs/wp-load.php';

//array($field_type, $echo_string, $id, $rows)
$fields = array(
    array('checkbox','Field 1','fieldname1','1'),
    array('checkbox','Field 2','fieldname2','1'),
    array('textarea','Field 3','fieldname3','3'),
    array('textarea','Field 4','fieldname4','3'),
    array('textarea','Field 5','fieldname5','3'),
    array('text','Field 6','fieldname6','1'),
    array('text','Field 7','fieldname7','1'),
    array('text','Field 8','fieldname8','1'),
    array('text','Field 9','fieldname9','1'),
    array('text','Field 10','fieldname10','1'),
    array('echo','Message 1','','1')
);

?>
<div class="wrap">
    <h2><?php _e('WTDomCheck Setup', 'wtdomcheck') ?></h2>
    <form method="post" action="options.php">

        <?php settings_fields( 'wtdomcheck-settings' ); ?>

        <div id="poststuff">
            <div class="postbox">
            <h3> <?php _e('Result Settings', 'wtdomcheck') ?></h3>
                <div class="inside">
                    <table class="form-table">
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys,

I found the problem by myself..

Original and wrong code:

```
$this->pages = [
            [
                'page_title' => 'WT Domain Check', 
                'menu_title' => 'WTDomCheck', 
                'capability' => 'manage_options', 
                'menu_slug'  => 'wtdomaincheck', 
                'callback'   => $this->LoadSettingTemplate(), 
                'icon_url'   => 'dashicons-store', 
                'position'   => 117
            ]
        ];
```

Corrected line:

```
'callback'   => array($this,'LoadSettingTemplate'),
```